# 301 Redirect and Url Rewrite in Same Rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite urls and redirect the old requests to the new urls permanently.  It's important to get the 301 recognized by Google to maintain the indexed pages.

Old Url: example.com/buy-productname-category-item/rest-of-url.html

New Url: example.com/productname-item/rest-of-url.html

Basically removing "buy-" and "category-" from the first part of the url.  The rest of the urls all follow the same structure.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


# this rule sends root requests to index.html, which is then sent by the next rule to /php/page.php 

# sends all requests for .html files to page.php for service
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/mockups
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/rss
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /php/page.php?uri=$1 [NC]
### ^ the most important rule

#---- remove buy- and ABC from urls
# the uri is being changed and page.php can't find it so it handles it as 404
RewriteRule buy-(.+)-ABC-123/(.+)$ /$1-123/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Please let me know why the above code is not working and also let me know if the [L,R=301] is actually what I need here.

Comment: I have since changed the rule but now I am getting a 404 error :    RedirectMatch 301 /buy-jay-z-concert-tickets/(.*) /jay-z-tickets/$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / #modify rewrite base according to your directory structure
RewriteRule buy-(.+)-category-(.+)/(.+)$ /$1-$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

**Update**

I think if you place the above rewrite statements above your original .htaccess code (after rewriteengine on), it'll map your request to the right page, i.e., `/page/page.php` with your URL in `$_GET['uri']`, i.e., `[uri] => productname-item/rest-of-url.html`. In that page you can parse the URL (like probably you're already doing) and extract the values.

**Final .htaccess code**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


# ######### new code ###
RewriteBase / #modify rewrite base according to your directory structure
RewriteRule buy-(.+)-category-(.+)/(.+)$ /$1-$2/$3 [L,R=301]
# ######################


# this rule sends root requests to index.html, which is then sent by the next rule to /php/page.php 
# sends all requests for .html files to page.php for service
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/mockups
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/rss
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /php/page.php?uri=$1 [NC]
### ^ the most important rule
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` character. It has no special meaning, unless used in character class between `range`.

Comment: This seems to get the url I am looking for, however, I am getting a 404 error... Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: do you have rewrite statement for handling the new URL? I believe you don't. Please post the rewrite rules (or complete htaccess) that mapped the old URL to the actual server resource or script URL.

Comment: I guess not... I was hoping that this one rule could handle both -- I am testing this on a different server.  1 min while I try it on the actual server.

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the uri is being sent to a handler which interprets what page it is and such.  When I change the uri with this rule, it is not finding what it's looking for in the database.  I will post more of the htaccess above.

Comment: If I add your code below the rewrite conditions, it is ignored.  If I add it above, the rule causes a 404 because the handler cannot recognize the uri

Comment: I will try this, it may take some time and effort because the only variable that I have to work with is the page uri.